# Notification play /pause mediplayer присвоить действие

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Изменил код согласно ответа,но ничего не происходит по нажатию кнопок в уведомлении:
Заметил такое поведение:   `getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);` удаляю данную строку и уведомление работает, но вылетает, а если оставить данную строку то ничего не происходит

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    Notify();//вызываю уведомление,когда свернул приложение
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

private PendingIntent makePendingIntent(String action) {
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, new Intent(action), 0);
}

public void Notify() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(),
            0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play_button)
            .setTicker("текст")
            .setContentTitle("текст")
            .setContentText("Нажмите чтобы вернуться в приложение")
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_white_48dp, "Pause", makePendingIntent(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK_PLAY) )
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled_white, "Play", makePendingIntent( BROADCAST_PLAYBACK_PAUSE));
    NotificationManagerCompat manager =  NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext());
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: `Notify();//вызываю уведомление,когда свернул приложение` наталкивает на мысль, что вы хотите уведомления при свернутом приложении обрабатывать, так не получится. Activity (и фрагмент) в остановленном состоянии никакой код выполнять не будут и естественно обработка нажатия кнопок и метод playAllSongs вызван не будет. Переносите в плеер в сервис.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov
так же в сервис переношу сам плеер?

Comment: Да и плеер и всю обработку интентов. Нотификации (`PendingIntent.getService(...)`) и активити (`startService(...)`) будут слать сервису интенты, которые в `onStartCommand` уже будут вызывать ваши методы `playAllSongs`, `pause` и т.д. Все будет работать в фоне.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov
доступ же к плееру из фрагмента я через экземпляр класса получаю?

Comment: нет, из фрагмента тоже отправляйте интенты. getActivity().startService(...). Обратную связь из сервиса в активити (т.е. позицию плеера передавать, например) можно сделать разными методами (это уже отдельный вопрос, на ru.SO тоже обсуждался). Вообще в примерах от гугла есть реализация плеера, посмотрите, основная идея там довольно простая https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/RandomMusicPlayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо реализовать BroadcastReceiver. Судя по тому, что вы создаете MediaPlayer во фрагменте вам может подойти создание ресивера в том же фрагменте:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK_PLAY)){
            playAllSongs();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK_PAUSE)){
            pause();
        }
    }
};
```

В onResume подписываетесь:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK_PLAY);
    intentFilter.addAction(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK_PAUSE);
getActivity().registerReceiver(mReciver, intentFilter);
```

И потом onPause не забыть отписаться:

```
getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
```

Еще вы не показали makePendingIntent. Он должен быть примерно таким:

```
private PendingIntent makePendingIntent(String action) {
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, new Intent(action), 0);
}
```

ЗЫ Для нотификаций стоит использовать NotificationCompat.Builder (полезные отличия есть, см гугл)

```
public void showNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(),
            0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_share)
            .setTicker("текст")
            .setContentTitle("текст")
            .setContentText("Нажмите чтобы вернуться в приложение")
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_white_48dp, "Pause", makePendingIntent(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK_PLAY) )
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled_white, "Play", makePendingIntent(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK_PAUSE));
    NotificationManagerCompat manager =  NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext());
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

ЗЫ А вообще стоит подумать о переносе `MediaPlayer` в сервис. Надо будет поменять `pendingIntent`'ы для action: вместо `getBroadcast` сделать `getService` и ловить эти интенты в `onStartCommand` сервиса и `BroadcastRecevier` будет не нужен.

Comment: изменил код согласно вашего ответа.....не получился результат, код в шапке темы

Comment: Вот код активити (с фрагментом не проверял) https://gist.github.com/ivanovsuper/6d32b86e65733601bffc4d09a7ebf1de
Попробуйте сначала в activity реализовать... Но вообще, это тупиковый путь, смотрите второй ЗЫ в овете.

Comment: гуглил,только ничего толкового не нашел..оф.документация не всю суть отражает

Comment: что-то ничего не пашет..пробовал отлавливать в логах нажатие..ничего не видит

Comment: смотрите комментарий под вопросом. вы ожидаете не того поведения. активити в фоне не будет работать. ответ подразумевает работу ресивера только когда приложение активно, т.е. почти бесполезно в вашем случае.